# Ansible synchronize module permissions issue

Tags: ansible

Remote Server's "/home"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZtge.png)

Remote Server User
 1. bitnami
 2. take02
 3. take03
 4. take04

But local Host are only ubuntu users.

I would like to copy the "home" directory of REMOTE HOST as ansible, 
keeping the OWNER information.

This is my playbook:

```
---
- hosts: discovery_bitnami
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: "Creates directory"
      local_action: >
        file path=/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}/home/ state=directory

    - name: "remote-to-local sync test"
      become_method: sudo
      synchronize:
        mode: pull
        src: /home/
        dest: /tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}/home
        rsync_path: "sudo rsync"
```

Playbook result is:

```
PLAY [discovery_bitnami] *******************************************************

TASK [Creates directory] *******************************************************
ok: [discovery_bitnami -> localhost]

TASK [remote-to-local sync test] ***********************************************
fatal: [discovery_bitnami]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/red_LightsailDefaultPrivateKey.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' \"bitnami@54.236.34.197:/home/\" \"/tmp/discovery_bitnami/home\"", "failed": true, "msg": "rsync: failed to set times on \"/tmp/discovery_bitnami/home/.\": Operation not permitted (1)\nrsync: recv_generator: mkdir \"/tmp/discovery_bitnami/home/bitnami\" failed: Permission denied (13)\n*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***\nrsync: recv_generator: mkdir \"/tmp/discovery_bitnami/home/take02\" failed: Permission denied (13)\n*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***\nrsync: recv_generator: mkdir \"/tmp/discovery_bitnami/home/take03\" failed: Permission denied (13)\n*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***\nrsync: recv_generator: mkdir \"/tmp/discovery_bitnami/home/take04\" failed: Permission denied (13)\n*** Skipping any contents from this failed directory ***\nrsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [generator=3.1.1]\n", "rc": 23}
    to retry, use: --limit @/home/ubuntu/work/esc_discovery/ansible_test/ansible_sync_test.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
discovery_bitnami          : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

But,
failed "cmd" works fine run with `sudo` on the console.

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/red_PrivateKey.pem -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o Port=22' --rsync-path=\"sudo rsync\" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' bitnami@54.236.34.197:/home/ /tmp/discovery_bitnami/home
```

How do I run "task" with sudo?

ps. remove `become: yes` then all permission is "ubuntu"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjgHD.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are out of options for the `synchronize` module. It runs locally without `sudo` and [it's hardcoded](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/files/synchronize.py#L0394).

On the other hand, in the first task you create a directory under `/tmp` as root, so the permissions are limited to the root user. As a result you get "*permissions denied*" error.

Either:

- refactor the code so that you don't need root permissions for the local destination (or add `become: no` for the task `"Creates directory"`), as you use archive option which implies permissions preservation, this might not be an option;

or:

- create your own version of the `synchronize` module and add `sudo` to the front of the `cmd` variable;

or:

- use the `command` module with `sudo /usr/bin/rsync` as the call.

Mind that `synchronize` module is a non-standard one, there were [changes in the past](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13825) regarding the accounts used, and [requests for the changes](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16215).

---

On top of everything, the current documentation for the module is pretty confusing. On one hand it states strongly:

> The user and permissions for the synchronize dest are those of the `remote_user` on the destination host or the `become_user` if `become=yes` is active.

But in another place it only hints that the source and destination meaning is reversed when using `pull` mode:

> In pull mode the remote host in context is the source.

So for the case from this question, the following passage is relevant, even though it incorrectly states the "src":

> The user and permissions for the synchronize src are those of the user running the Ansible task on the local host (or the remote_user for a delegate_to host when delegate_to is used).

Comment: Thank you!! 
but, 
I would like to copy the "home" directory of REMOTE HOST as ansible, 
keeping the OWNER information.

Remote Server User
 1. bitnami
 2. take02
 3. take03
 4. take04

But local Host are only ubuntu users.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what the question explained. Do you expect me to respond to your comment?